# how to manipulate photos from album on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, photos

I have a project to do in which i have to 
-access to the photos of the iPhone albums
-make a multiple selection and save this selections
-send some of the selections to a web service and then get the photos back to the iPhone app(the photos have been modified during this time).

I really start with objective-c and iPhone-app coding and i wanted to know here what's possible and what isn't.

First it appears that we can't access to the photos by another way than the image picker. I found ELCImagePicker to do some multiple selections, are there other ways to do that?

In order to get the photos back from the web service, it appears that i need to copy this photos to the folder of the application(we can't rewrite on the photo album). Is that possible to do that for an important number of photos? What is the space disk available for an application?

in order to save the selections done with elcImagePicker, i need to keep some identifier of the different photos but i didn't find anywhere how to find the name of the photo. Any solution for that?

Would it be possible(and not too heavy) to save the attribute NSData obtained with UIImageJPEGRepresentation in my core data model to remember which photos were selected?

Thanks for your answers and sorry for my bad english ...